# Upgrading Eclipse from Kepler to Luna fails in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, eclipse

Trying to use Eclipse's auto-update to go from the Kepler release to the new Luna (using Ubuntu 14.04). Got everything set, started Eclipse in admin mode, and selected <kbd>Help</kbd>><kbd>Check for updates</kbd>.

It appeared to be working, until it failed with this message:

```
An error occurred while uninstalling
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.platform_root 4.3.2.v20140221-1852 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
Backup of file /opt/eclipse/.eclipseproduct failed.
File that was copied to backup could not be deleted: /opt/eclipse/.eclipseproduct
```

Kind of seems like some sort of permissions problem, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Is it still relevant?